# Dataframe and images to PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I have multiple data frames and images which I wanted to save in a PDF with proper alignment. I am able to save the data frames into PDF file using below code:

```
    df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table", con) 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    the_table = ax.table(cellText=df1.values, colLabels=df1.columns, loc='center',
                         )
    pp = PdfPages("static/images/foo.pdf")
    pp.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
    pp.close()
```

The result is:

[image]

Similarly I have multiple images and data frames, not sure how to align it properly and provide the right title for each object. The result am expecting is:

[image]

Can I do that using HTML within Python?